# Convert CEditor to ICModelEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse plugin which extends some of the features provided by `CDT`.
The problem is that the plugin is supposed to support multiple `CDT versions`.

One of the plugin classes extends the `SelectionParseAction` class from `CDT`:

```
class CustomSelectionParseAction extends SelectionParseAction {

    public CustomSelectionParseAction(CEditor editor) {
        super(editor);
    }
}
```

The constructor signature of `SelectionParseAction` changed from `CDT 8.*` to `CDT 9.*`([diff link](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/commit/5b86da58ad14340d7062b5583c68227ef32a3a5c#diff-2f3e14b58ae6214efb983939913484e5)).

`public SelectionParseAction(ICEditor editor)`
became
`public SelectionParseAction(ICModelBasedEditor editor)`

Since the input for my `CustomSelectionParseAction` will remain an `CEditor` object, how could I support both CDT class constructors?

Comment: The reason Eclipse CDT felt free to change the signature was because this is an **internal** class. You are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by extending such classes.

Comment: @greg-449 I am just the unlucky maintainer of the plugin. I don't blame the CDT changes and I am totally aware that the extended class is `not API` and the `access is discouraged`. However, I was wondering if I can find a solution to patch this situation.

Comment: `CEditor` implements `ICModelBasedEditor`, so shouldn't it just work?

Comment: It doesn't because at run time it tries to call the constructor `super(CEditor)` which doesn't exist anymore, therefore `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. I am thinking to copy in the plugin the old implementation of `SelectionParseAction` and just use that one until we get rid of the `non-API code`.

Comment: I see... the change is source-compatible for your plugin, but not binary-compatible. Can you distribute different builds of your plugin for CDT 8.x and CDT 9.x?

Comment: @HighCommander4 That would be the last resort which would break the compatibility and duplicate the code, but unless I find a different solution, this one would be it